# How do I apply radius properly to the end points of this shape?

Tags: path, sketch-app

I want a radius on the two end points similar to the other corners.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kg6vznyfnkcxm2e/AAC_NSaCXkcRZvgsRXM0Yy4Ya?dl=0

Comment: Hi Chovy, what have you tried so far? To get good answers it's best to keep us updated on what you have tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Double click the shape until anchor points show up.
2. Select a corner.
3. Make sure the anchor connection is set to "Straight"
4. Adjust the Corner radius.
5. Repeat for all the other corners

[image]

Download result: http://ge.tt/9h6e5a22/v/0

Apologies for somewhat late answer, I just found out how to do this myself and remembered this old question, wanted to make sure to answer it so other people can learn from it as well.